# OnUpdate Firebase Database Trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a basic firebase trigger, that when a condition in my realtime database is changed will fire the trigger leading to a FCM notification, but I am stuck on the first step and cannot make the Onupdate trigger work correctly.
My database has no users at the moment and only has this condition inside of it, I tried searching frantically, but have been unable to find something to make this work.

```
        // This code sets up the Firebase SDK to create functions and triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// This gives the Firebase Admin SDK Access to the database
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



exports.sendNotification = functions.database
        .ref("/condition/{}").onCreate(event => {
    if (event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists())
        {
            return; 
        }
});
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The issue is that I change the condition value in the database and that's fine, but in the console for the Functions, there have been no executions ran, which to my understanding means that the code doesn't check for any update from the condition value.

Comment: Hi Peter, yep, that's it, thanks a lot, why didn't I see it before, Thanks!

Comment: Tinkering with a Firebase example and trying to tailor it to my needs, did remove it and change create to update with your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `onCreate()` that is why the function does not get executed if you change condition value in the database.

Now if you add new data at location `condition`, then onCreate() will get triggered.

`onUpdate()`, which triggers when data is updated in the Realtime Database.

`onWrite()`, which triggers when data is created, updated, or deleted in the Realtime Database.

`onDelete()`, which triggers when data is deleted from the Realtime Database.

Try and use `onWrite()` or `onUpdate()` if you want it to trigger when data is changed.

more info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: Thank you ever so much, you've saved a lot of headache! It works perfectly fine and now to add on FCM to it.